# How can I build my own deck canopy?

Tags: deck

I'd like to build my own deck canopy, and not purchase those retractable awnings that don't seem to last so well out here in Colorado (can be very windy).

I have the 'basic' idea in my head but are there any good resource or plans for building a proper, safe, reliable deck canopy?

Edit: I was thinking two posts to connect to my existing deck posts.  Our deck is raised.  Then a header piece at the front of the deck, connected to the posts to which I would take a runner board for each side and connect that to the house.  I want to use a retractable awning.  Does this make some sense?

I like this idea: http://www.diynetwork.com/how-to/how-to-build-a-shade-canopy-frame-to-a-deck/index.html

Comment: If you share what's in *your* head, it might make it easier for folks here to share what's in *their* heads.  Then you'll get a better more accurate answer, and we'll all benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what's in your head, I'd say start with some basic deck pergola designs, and modify them to accommodate the canopy style you're envisioning.

[Basic pergola for a deck instructions](http://www.lowes.com/cd_Build+a+Pergola_294992910_)